# Run time error with map in Visual Studio 2010 x64

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have been trying to create a sample application in Visual Studio 2010. I am not getting what is the problem as the code is perfectly compiling, but is giving run-time error. Here is the code:

```
#include <Map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    map <int, string> *sss = new map<int, string>;
    sss->at(0) = "Jan";
    sss->at(1) = "Feb";
    sss->at(2) = "Mar";
    sss->at(3) = "Apr";
    sss->at(4) = "May";
    sss->at(5) = "Jun";
    string current = NULL;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("daily_work.txt");
    myfile << "*****   DAILY WORK   *****" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        string month = sss->at(i);
        for(int j = 1; j < 31; j++)
        {
            stringstream ss;
            ss << j;
            current = ss.str();
            current.append(" ");
            current.append(month);
            current.append(" = ");
            myfile << current << endl;
        }

        current = "";
    }

    printf("Completed!");
    myfile.close();
    sss->clear();
    delete sss;
    sss = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is thrown at line no 2 in main.

```
sss->at(0) = "Jan";
```

Please find the error here:

[image]

Comment: at() throws if the element does not exist, correct? EDIT: see jrok's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `map.at` does access at the element 0. You have just created the map, so you element 0 is empty.  Use `insert` and read this documentation about maps.

[c++ reference map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

I suggest you also to avoid `for 1 ... 6`, iterator is the preferred way to cycle a map.
In this way, if you add element to your map, you don't need to to anything else, the loop will automatically adjust itself.

Use this sample:

```
typedef std::map<int, string>::iterator it_type;
for(it_type iterator = map.begin(); iterator != map.end(); iterator++) {
    // iterator->first = key
    // iterator->second = value
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info! :)

Answer (score 4):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at:

```
Returns a reference to the mapped value of the element with key equivalent to key.
If no  such element exists, an exception of type std::out_of_range is thrown.
```

You need:

```
map <int, string> sss;
sss[ 0 ] = "Jan";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `at` function expects the entry to already exist, which it doesn't.

You can use the normal indexing operator `[]` to create entries if they doesn't exist. But for this I recommend you to not use `new` to allocate a `map` pointer.

```
map <int, string> sss;

sss[0] = "Jan";
// etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

map::at requires an index of an existing element. To create a new element use operator[]:

```
sss[0] = "Jan";
sss[1] = "Feb";
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers have already explained the problem, but seeing how you seem to be compiling C++11 (using [`at()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/)) why not use the new initializer list way:

```
auto sss = new map<int, string> = {
    {0, "Jan"}, 
    {1, "Feb"},
    {2, "Mar"},
    {3, "Apr"},
    {4, "May"},
    {5, "Jun"},
};
```

As an aside you could build up your output string neater by not having that `currrent` variable at all, just make more use of your stringstring object.

```
stringstream ss;
ss << j << " " << month << " = \n");
myfile << ss.str();
```